# SMTPClient - Error while sending mail - Connection attempt failed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, smtp, smtpclient

I am using below code to send mails, it works for Gmail SMTP & also some other SMTPs.

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient
                    {
                        Host = data.SMTPServer,                 
                        Port = data.PortNo,
                        EnableSsl = false,
                        DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                        UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                        Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(senderID, senderPassword),
                        Timeout = 30000,
                    };
                    
                    smtp.Send(message);
```

But for 1 client, it throws back the error.
A connection attempted failed because the connected party did not respond after a period of time.

How to solve this?

Comment: What exactly is your question? To me the Exception-message is pretty clear: A Timeout where your code did not get any response from the server.

Comment: SMTP is different depending on the email carrier.  So what works on one carrier may not work on a different carrier.  If your application is on a Corporate Network that has an outlook server you cannot send email to a outside email server like gmail.  What works on your home computer will give error at work.  SMTP also requires the FROm address and the credential to be from the same account.  Also some networks will block NetworkCredentials and you have to use Default Credentials.